# Magento 2 can't upload image to product

Tags: magento2, product-images, products, admin-panel

I can't upload some images to products, the weird thing is that it's just with some products that have small images, like 115x200px or something like that.
I know it has to be something with the configuration of Magento, because I can upload images from 30kb or 40kb, but the small one that are like 11kb can't upload them.

Here is the error I'm getting.

[image]

Things I've tried:

1. Give permissions to pub/media folder, it's ok
2. Clean cache and flush cache
3. Reindex
4. Change image extension to png (did not work either)
5. tried different images (it worked, but it's useless because I need images from specific products)
6. logout and login from admin panel.

Images does not seem corrupt because I can open them and resize without problem, even change format.
What could it be?

Thanks!

Comment: Which image adapter you are using (by default it is PHP GD2 but also the ImageMagic available. They have support of different image type)? Could you upload the image you are using somewhere? I would test it on my magento.

Comment: where can I see what Image adapter am I using? on PHP ini or where? tthanks!

Comment: You can check it in `Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Image Processing Settings > Image Adapter` (dev mode must be enabled, otherwise this section is hidden)

Comment: I'm using php gd2